# Why is a value gotten from a table cell not working when passed as a condition in an IF/ELSE statement embedded in an array of objects loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code samples.

The table rows are generated automatically and appended to the tbody. When I perform the click function on the Delete/Trash Icon, I get the value of the cell which is that *currentRow*, but then when I try to use it inside the for-loop and if-else condition, it doesn't work. I am trying to do so so I can delete the user from both the table and the storage as well (using LocalStorage for storage)-array of objects.

```js
let sampleArray = 
[
    {
        attendanceCount: 0
        fullName: "Ezeugo Obieze"
        password: "qtvpr3h933i"
        userPhoneNumber: "07060858438"
    },
    
    {
        attendanceCount: 0
        fullName: Felistus Ezekiel"
        password: "tcph4aym3mb"
        userPhoneNumber: "07087032997"
    }

]


let listAllEmployees = () => {
  return userDetails.forEach( (element) => {
      $("#employees-table").append(`
        <tr>
            <td> ${element.fullName} </td>
            <td class="userMobile">${element.userPhoneNumber                    </td>
            <td> ${element.password}</td>
            <td class="centerText">${element.attendanceCount}                   </td>
            <td class="centerText"><i class="fa fa-trash icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
         </tr`);
      });
 };

 $("#employees-table").on("click", ".icon", function() {
   let currentRow =  $(this).closest("tr").children("td.userMobile").text();
   console.log(currentRow) //test if the value was gotten
     for(let index = 0; index < userDetails.length; index++) {
          if ( currentRow === userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber)            console.log(useDetails)
       }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody id="employees-table"> 
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td class="userMobile">09060858438</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td class="centerText"> 0</td>
        <td class="centerText"> <i class="fa fa-trash icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ${element.userPhoneNumber is missing a  closing bracket

Comment: is userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber an integer? maybe parseInt(currentRow,10) === userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber

Comment: @BryanDellinger I have closed the brackets properly but the issue still pesists. Also, userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber is a string and so is currentRow. using parseInt on currentRow will reduce the length of the phoneNumber which is meant to be 11 digits like so: 07060858438

Comment: maybe you could add userDetails array to your question so it can be debugged.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I have added a sample of the userDetails array of Objects

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to debug the code and found the error.
Chrome DevTool was not displaying any errors, so I had to track each value gotten from the table and array, consoled to the browser, and found out that they weren't equal:

> **sample code**

// data from the table

```
targetUserMobile = currentRow.children("td.userMobile").text() returned " 09060858438 ";
```

// data from the array

```
userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber  returned "09060858438"
```

// when compared

```
userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber !== targetUserMobile
```

so I had to use the trim() method to clear the whitespaces before and after the number and it worked like so:

```
userDetails[index].userPhoneNumber === targetUserMobile.trim()
```